# Being a movie lover I like watching lots of movies vs Being a movie lover,I like watching lots of movies

Tags: grammar

As I am a movie lover, I like watching lots of movies.

By using participle rule,we can write -1) Being a movie lover, I like watching lots of movies.

But I have seen many times this type of sentences without "comma" in the newspaper - 2) I like watching lots of movies being a movie lover.

My question is, is the number 2 correct? If it's correct,then in which rule ?

Comment: The text of your OP would appear to be asking a different question to the title. Certainly *I like watching lots of movies* has a completely different meaning to *I like lots of movies*.

Comment: I have already corrected it.Thanks for mentioning the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Neither. Your use of the word "like" is redundant. Also, using the word "movie" twice in the same sentence sounds awkward. Below is my suggestion for a rewrite:

As a movie lover, I watch a lot of films.

Comment: please consider these sentences 1) Being homesick , I don't want to go aboard 2) I don't want to go aboard being homesick. 

Please tell me the difference  between using comma and not using comma.