# Being a cricketer,I have to practice every day to be fit vs I have to practice everyday being a cricketer to be fit

Tags: grammar

1)Being a cricket player,I have to practice every day to be fit. (using participle rule )

2)I have to practice every day being a cricket player to be fit. (what about this? )

Please tell me the difference between using comma and not using comma?

I just wanna know the difference no matter how strong or weak my sentences are.ignore that.

Comment: What's the difference between this question and your previous question, [I don't want to go abroad, being homesick vs I don't want to go abroad being homesick](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/329768/i-dont-want-to-go-abroad-being-homesick-vs-i-dont-want-to-go-abroad-being-hom) and [Being a movie lover I like watching lots of movies vs Being a movie lover,I like watching lots of movies](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/329572/being-a-movie-lover-i-like-watching-lots-of-movies-vs-being-a-movie-lover-i-like). Why do  you keep asking the same question?

Comment: please answer my question.I just wanna know comma+being vs without comma +being

Comment: Where did you find the sentence? In a grammar book? What does the book say? Did you write the sentence yourself?

Comment: I am so sorry for asking the same question thrice.but I haven't got my answer as of yet.

Comment: Why do you think you haven't got any answer yet? You didn't show us where you found the sentence, what your research shows, what you think the difference is. You need to delete two of the questions by clicking on **delete** and be more specific on what you want to know with your own research.

Comment: I have seen many times in the newspaper like these sentences.sometimes they use comma and sometimes they don't. I am confused.

Comment: I have done this.Maybe, it takes some time to be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how your sentences read to me, if you try to get to the deeper level.

1) Since/because I am a cricket player, (that is why) I have to practice every day to be fit.

The first part of the sentence is the explanation of the second part. It's the reason you do the next part.

2) I have to (practice being a cricket player every day) to be fit.

Here it sounds like the only possible way for you to be fit is by practicing being a cricket player every day.

So, to get to the point of your comma question, in sentence 1, the introductory phrase is incomplete by itself, and takes a comma to show its connectedness with the second part, where you tell me what it is I need to know about your being a cricketer. "Being a cricketer" is not a sentence alone and I know to expect more to come.

In the second sentence, the whole entire phrase in parentheses above is functioning as one element. It could just as easily be replaced by run/swim/throw a discus/do 100 one-handed push-ups, but it completes the idea that is begun with the "to" in "I have to_______."

I think the clumsiness of the second sentence comes from the order in which the information is presented. Your first sentence gives you some info, takes a breath, and explains why it was shared. The second just starts jamming everything in, a feeling which mostly comes from, possibly, the time info (every day) being put in between the "to" and the "_____" mentioned above. "I have to every day run/ I have to every day swim" just aren't constructions typically used. (and to make it more confusing, would probably typically be set off by commas "I have to, every day, run) So, a more natural placement would read "I have to practice being a cricket player every day to be fit."

Commas were always explained to me as places to pause, which is probably why I put them all over the place, most likely incorrectly. But, if you can pare down your sentences to their basic elements and see how they fit together as bits and pieces, or put in other, similar words and try them out, you'll usually be fine.

Short answer is, introductory phrase takes a comma. Verb phrase doesn't.

Comment: Thanks to you #clint for your great explanation. One more question - 1) I left room,singing a song. 2) I left room singing a song. 

Is there any difference in meaning?

Comment: Not really. It's sort of a pace thing. Similar to the other one, if you over pause where the comma is you can get a feel for the way the sentences will sound.

1) I left the room....singing a song (not that it makes any difference, I just was).

2) I left a room singing a song. 
This gives both parts of the sentence equal weight. The leaving of the room and the singing of the song are both important here, whereas in (1) the singing part is just sort of tacked on as a little extra info that doesn't seem to effect anything.